# Accessing my MyApiService in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my first Xamarin Forms app and I'm trying to understand how I can access my `MyApiService` methods throughout the app. BTW, it's Xamarin Forms 5 app with a shell.

First, I created a `MyApiService` that has the `HttpClient` and makes `REST` calls to my backend API:

```
public class MyApiService : IMyApiSerice
{
   private static string baseUrl = "https://mybackendapi.com";
   private static HttpClient _client;

   public MyApiService()
   {
       _client = new HttpClient
       {
           BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
       };
   }

   public async Task<string>GetSomething()
   {
       var response = await _client.GetStringAsync("/something");

       return response.ToString();
   }
}
```

Then I added an interface for my service:

```
public interface IMyApiService
{
    Task<string> GetSomething();
}
```

Then I thought I needed to add my interface to the `DependencyService` so in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public App()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DependencyService.Register<IMyApiService>();
}
```

I'm now trying to consume the service in `OnAppearing()` method for one of my pages but the app keeps crashing.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I access `IMyApiService` methods throughout the app?

UPDATE:

This approach is correct. The mistake I was making was where I register the service. I needed to resolve the `interface` to the concrete class. Here's the corrected line of code:

`DependencyService.Register<IMyApiService, MyApiService>();`

Comment: Have you read up on the [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) in XF? The dependency service expects a per platform implementation to be registered, which doesn't look like you're doing that with the single class implementation. What you could do instead is just new up an instance of `MyApiService` and make the call that way.

Comment: https://xmonkeys360.com/2019/03/29/dependency-injection-with-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @NickPeppers Would I new up my service class in App.xaml’s constructor? I assume it needs to be initialized at the entry point.

Comment: Or new it up wherever I need to use it. I guess HttpClient being static, even if I new it up multiple times, there would still be only one instance of it

Comment: Yeah if you new it up wherever needed it should be fine since the HttpClient is static and thread-safe so if two different pages happen to be making the web request at the same time it'll work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps. That's the way I am doing it (Maybe a bit complicated but once understood it is easy to handle:

I create a data model which is including the fields from my database table:

```
public class Campaigns
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CampaignCode { get; set; }
        public string Offer { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ProposedStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ProposedEndeDate { get; set; }
        public string CRMGUID { get; set; }
        public long CampaignType { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public Uri ImageURL { get; set; }
    }
```

I have an API Controller for a specific table I want to us:

```
namespace EY365OCMobileApp.APIControllers
{
    public class CampaignController
    {
        IRestService restService;
        public CampaignController(IRestService service)
        {
            restService = service;
        }
        public Task<List<Campaigns>> GetCampaignsAsync(long campaignType)
        {
            return restService.GetCampaignsAsync(campaignType);
        }
    }
}
```

There we have an dependency to the RestService which looks like this:

```
public interface IRestService
{
      Task<List<Campaigns>> GetCampaignsAsync(long campaignType);
}
```

In the RestService.cs I have the access to the API via HTTP:

```
public async Task<List<Campaigns>> GetCampaignsAsync(long campaignType)
        {
            List<Campaigns> Campaigns = new List<Campaigns>();
            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.GetCampaigns + campaignType + " and Active eq true", string.Empty));
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Campaigns = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Campaigns>>(content);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await CreateNewBug.CreateANewBug(ex.Message,"Error in Module " + ex.Source,"\nMessage---\n{ 0}" + ex.Message + "\nInnerException---\n{ 0}" + ex.InnerException + "\nStackTrace---\n{ 0}" + ex.StackTrace + "\nTargetSite---\n{ 0}" + ex.TargetSite);
            }
            return Campaigns;
        }
```

The "Constants.GetCampaigns" is a variable which contains the URL like HTTPS://myapi.api.com/campaigns

To Get the results I added lazy loading for the controller into my app.xaml.cs

```
public static CampaignController CampaignController { get; private set; }
CampaignController _campaigncontroller;
        public CampaignController CampainController{ 
            get
            {      
            if(_campaigncontroller == null) 
            {
                    _campaigncontroller = new CampaignController(new RestService());
            }
            return _campaigncontroller;  
            }
        }
```

Now in the pages (for example in OnAppearing()) I do the following:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
                Campaigns = await (App.Current as App).CampainController.GetCampaignsAsync(1);
                CarouselView.ItemsSource = Campaigns;
                BindingContext = Campaigns;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await CreateNewBug.CreateANewBug(ex.Message,"Error in Module " + ex.Source,"\nMessage---\n{ 0}" + ex.Message + "\nInnerException---\n{ 0}" + ex.InnerException + "\nStackTrace---\n{ 0}" + ex.StackTrace + "\nTargetSite---\n{ 0}" + ex.TargetSite);
                ToastOptions toastOptions = Message.ShowMessage("An error was raised and a new bug created in our system.", "error");
                await this.DisplayToastAsync(toastOptions);
            }
        }
```

The await ....GetCampaignsAsync(1) returns me a list of all campaigns where the parameter 1 is met. I can bind these list to my List and show it in XAML.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code sample. I did figure out the problem in my code which seems to be a correct approach. I think your approach is fine too. I added an UPDATE section to the original post. Thanks again!

Comment: Great that you solved your problem!